# Finding all nth roots of a complex number in C#

Tags: c#, .net, numeric

Consider a generic complex number:

```
System.Numerics.Complex z = new System.Numerics.Complex(0,1); // z = i
```

And now consider the n-th root extraction operation of `z`. As you all know, when having a problem like `z^n = w` (having `z` and `w` complex numbers and `n` a positive not null integer) the equation returns `n` different complex numbers all residing on the complex circle having its radius equal to the module of `z` (`|z|`).

In the `System.Numerics` namespace I could not find such a method. I obviousle need some sort of method like this:

```
Complex[] NRoot(Complex number);
```

How can I find this method. Do I really need to implement it myself?

Comment: Is it possible to get/set the complex number by its polar coordinates? that would make the task way easier.

Comment: There is a `static Complex FromPolarCoordinates()`

Comment: I was going to say the same... However really there is no implementation of a generic method to extract the nth roots of a complex number?

Comment: I know it is not difficult to write such a method, but I suppose that an optimized implementation exists, using the mathematical definition might not be the best possible solution!

Comment: Someone did edit my post title removing "C#" from it. I disagree with this because it is the essence of my question. As I have explained, I am not looking for an algorithm to find the roots, I need to know whether the .NET framework (in particular, C# libraries) already implements a method to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I find this method.

You can't, it's not built into the Framework.

> Do I really need to implement it myself?

Yes.

Sorry if this comes across as a tad flip, I don't mean to, but I suspect that you already knew this would be the answer.

That said, there's no magic to it:

```
public static class ComplexExtensions {
    public static Complex[] NthRoot(this Complex complex, int n) {
        Contract.Requires(n > 0);
        var phase = complex.Phase;
        var magnitude = complex.Magnitude;
        var nthRootOfMagnitude = Math.Pow(magnitude, 1.0 / n);
        return
            Enumerable.Range(0, n)
                      .Select(k => Complex.FromPolarCoordinates(
                          nthRootOfMagnitude,
                          phase / n + k * 2 * Math.PI / n)
                      )
                      .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Most of the work is offloaded to the Framework. I trust that they've implemented `Complex.Phase`, `Complex.Magnitude` correctly (`(Complex complex) => Math.Sqrt(complex.Real * complex.Real + complex.Imaginary * complex.Imaginary)` is bad, Bad, BAD) and `Math.Pow` correctly.

Comment: Do you have a link to a proper implementation of complex magnitude should it turn out that .Net's is "bad, Bad, BAD"?

Comment: @Gabe: Nope, but it's pretty well-known. The problem is that the naive `|x + yi| = Sqrt(x^2 + y^2)` can overflow well before it should. It's very easily avoided with `|x + yi| = |x| Sqrt(1 + (y / x)^2) if |x| >= |y|, otherwise |y| * Sqrt(1 + (x / y)^2) if |x| < |y|` (this can still overflow). I suspect it's somewhere in [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/) but I don't have my copy handy right now. Like I said, I *trust* that the Framework got this right. That's possibly a mistake, given the infamous binary search overflow bug that was in Java, something they should have known.

Comment: @Gabe: I just tested (someone with access to a code decompiler can do better) on `new Complex(Math.Sqrt(Double.MaxValue), Math.Sqrt(DoubleMaxValue))` and the Framework gets it right whereas the naive would overflow and get it wrong.

Comment: A quick look in ILSpy shows an implementation as you describe (with an added check for 0, obviously).

Comment: Guess it can't be helped. Thanks for you efforts Jason and thank you for posting code!

Comment: @Gabe: Here's a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypot) on the subject.